# jquery if checkbox checked add value true

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make jquery click function if checkBox checked then status value set to 'true', if not cheked value set to 'false'?

if I check checkbox 1 , then status 1 set to true
if I check checkbox 2 , then status 2 set to true
if I check checkbox 3 , then status 3 set to true

```html
<div class="form-group">    
  <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Checkbox 1</label>
   <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
   <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> Checkbox 2</label>
   <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
  <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> Checkbox 3</label>
   <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: your question is not very clear can you clarify. also include the JS in OP

Comment: Just bind a `change` event with `checkboxes`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your input is within `<lable>`, use `parent().next()` to set the value.

Here is the working example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form-group input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parent().next().val('true')
    } else
      $(this).parent().next().val('false');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Checkbox 1</label>
  <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> Checkbox 2</label>
  <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> Checkbox 3</label>
  <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() { 
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
       $(this).parent().next().val("true");
    }else{
       $(this).parent().next().val("false");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {  $(this).closest('label').next('input[type="text"]').val('true');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('label').next('input[type="text"]').val('false');
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">    
  <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Checkbox 1</label>
   <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
   <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> Checkbox 2</label>
   <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
  <label><input name="checkBox[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> Checkbox 3</label>
   <input name="status[]" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: @silviazulinka Welcome brother

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div class="form-group">    
   <input name="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="1">
   <input name="status" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
   <input name="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="2">
   <input name="status" type="text" value="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">    
   <input name="checkBox" type="checkbox" value="3">
   <input name="status" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

and the jquery script

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).next('input[type="text"]').val('true');
    } else {
        $(this).next('input[type="text"]').val('false');
    }
}).change();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/831mjzr1/

Comment: Where is the `<label>` ?

Comment: @silviazulinka. Thanks. But this answer is missing the `<label>`. This answer will fail if `<label>` is added.